# What is the earliest recorded reference to a bubble floating in the air?

Tags: science, everyday-life

What is the earliest reference to a bubble floating in the air?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Judging by the wiki entry on [soap bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_bubble), soap bubbles (which I presume is the ones you mean) go back at least 400 years. Air bubbles in water go way further back -- as in Archimedes and earlier.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy: Are they floating in the air?

Comment: @Tim: given the description I would assume so: "Soap bubbles have been used as entertainment for at least 400 years, as evidenced by 17th-century Flemish paintings showing children blowing bubbles with clay pipes." But quite frankly, I can't imagine it was only discovered in the 17th century. Soap was known as early as 2200BCE.

Comment: Interesting question. Soap is thousands of years old, but older forms of soap were very different to today's - more like a paste of ash and fat or oil - and modern detergents often gets their bubbles from special chemicals. There are plenty of histories of the soap industry, but none seem to touch on this important issue.

Comment: [This 1630 painting](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Adriaen_Hanneman_Two_Boys_Blowing_Bubbles.JPG), visible on the wikipedia page referred to by @DenisdeBernardy clearly show bubbles floating in the air

Comment: All that is required to form a bubble is a suitable air pressure, to deform the water to the limits of its surface tension.  As the surface tension of water is quite high, a surfactant is required to reduce the surface tension.  All forms of soap will do this, though modern detergents are generally superior.  Thus any washer-woman with children to entertain, and a few hollow reeds, could have carried out this demonstration.

Answer (score 8):

[Jean Froissart wrote](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Z0mjDwAAQBAJ&q=soap%20bubbles#v=onepage&q=soap%20bubble&f=false)

> And I often, with a little tube, Made a soap bubble fly from the
>   water.

I'm not sure when he wrote this but he died in [about 1405](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Froissart).

Also, there's a picture of a monkey maybe blowing a bubble.

[image]

The [text under the picture says](https://blogs.bl.uk/digitisedmanuscripts/2012/04/index.html)

> Detail from a full border of a monkey playing a game (possibly blowing
>   bubbles?), from the Isabella Breviary, Southern Netherlands (Bruges),
>   late 1480s and before 1497, British Library, Additional 18851, f. 470v

OK, it's not quite in the air but it's close. There are some better ones at http://willscommonplacebook.blogspot.com/2013/02/blowing-bubbles.html but they aren't as old. Here's one example from around 1617 in a picture called Homo Bulla by Karel van Sichem.

[image]